# PKCS#11: Can C_GetMechanismInfo() return CKR_OK on a disabled mechanism?

Tags: pkcs11

According to [PKCS#11 v2.20](http://www.emc.com/emc-plus/rsa-labs/standards-initiatives/pkcs-11-cryptographic-token-interface-standard.htm), "`C_GetMechanismInfo` obtains information about a particular mechanism **possibly supported** by a token." Does that mean `C_GetMechanismInfo()` can return `CKR_OK` on a **temporarily disabled** mechanism? For example, if `C_GetMechanismList()` does not return `CKM_MD5` in the result then is it OK for `C_GetMechanismInfo(CKM_MD5)` to return `CKR_OK`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The caller may invoke `C_GetMechanismInfo` for a mechanism that does not appear in the list returned by `C_GetMechanisList`, where the latter "*... is used to obtain a list of mechanism types supported by a token*".

I believe that's the reason they added the adverb **possibly**.

I am not sure what you refer to as "temporary disabled". To me, if the token is not in a state that allows a certain mechanism (temporarilly or permanently), `C_GetMechanismInfo` should return `CKR_MECHANISM_INVALID` or at the very least not `CKR_OK`.

Comment: Thanks. On Solaris, one mechanism can be disabled by the `cryptoadm` command.